# Stretching a list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, list

An example: I have a list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` and I need to "stretch" it to lenght 20, with existing values distributed as evenly as possible,"missing" values replaced with `None` and the resulting list has to start with 1 and end with 8.

There are 8-1 spaces between the values in the original list and and 20-8 None values to distribute, so we can put a single None to every "space".

```
[1, None, 2, None, 3, None, 4, None, 5, None, 6, None, 7, None, 8]
```

Now we still have 12-7 `None` values to distribute and we can distribute 4 of those on every other space:

```
[1, None, None, 2, None, 3, None, None, 4, None, 5, None,None 6, None, 7, None,
    None, 8]
```

Now we have one left that we can assign randomly:

```
[1, None, None, 2, None, 3, None, None, 4, None, 5, None, None, 6, None, None 7, 
    None, None, 8]
```

Is there an algorithm that lets you fullfill a task like this? An implementation maybe?

Comment: Since this is not a standard problem, of course you won't get any pre-designed algorithm for it. You would have to make one.

Comment: Seeing your attempt at solving this problem would also be nice.

Comment: That last case doesn't look even to me; the gap between `5` and `6` is too wide.

Comment: Define "evenly as possible"; as @nneonneo says, your example doesn't seem very even.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basic idea: just linearly interpolate the new positions from the old positions. For simplicity, we use floor division, but you could get clever and use rounding division for a slightly more even distribution.

```py
def stretch_to(l, n):
    out = [None] * n
    m = len(l)
    for i, x in enumerate(l):
        out[i*(n-1)//(m-1)] = x

    return out
```

Sample:

```
>>> stretch_to(range(8), 20)
[0, None, 1, None, None, 2, None, None, 3, None, 4, None, None, 5, None, None, 6, None, None, 7]
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have n times in your first list and m items in the second. Something like this will work.

```
l2 = [None for I in range(m)]
for i, x in emumerate(l1):
    index = i * m / n
    l2[index] = l1[i]
```

You'll want to decide on edge case behavior, what to do if `m<n`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a terse alternative that I think is interesting:

```
def stretch(seq, n):
    seq = [seq[i * (len(seq) - 1) // (n - 1)] for i in range(n)]
    return [seq[0]] + [x if x != y else None for x, y in zip(seq[1:], seq)]
```

And based on that, an itertools-based version that doesn't make any copies of the list, returning an iterator that you can optionally convert into a list:

```
from itertools import tee, chain, izip
def stretch(seq, n):
    s1, s2 = tee(seq[i * (len(seq) - 1) // (n - 1)] for i in range(n))
    return chain((next(s1),), (x if x != y else None for x, y in izip(s1, s2)))
```